# Firebase RecyclerView Adapter onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from Firebase to my `RecyclerView` by `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` but it always set the list item to the initial value of the class

I am using data binding to set the class to a variable person.

Adapter class:

```
class RecyclerAdapterAllUser(options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PersonalInfo>) :
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PersonalInfo, RecyclerAdapterAllUser.Holder>(options) {
        private lateinit var binding: ListItemAllUserRecyclerBinding
    
        class Holder(val binding: ListItemAllUserRecyclerBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int, model: PersonalInfo) {
    
            binding.person = model
        }
    }
```

class

```
class PersonalInfo() {
    var name: String =""
    var nickName: String = ""
    private var age = 0

    constructor(name: String, nickName: String, age: Int) : this() {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
        this.nickName = nickName
    }
}
```

activity

```
class AllUsers : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAllUsresBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerAdapterAllUser
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_all_usres)
        binding.listItemAllUsersActivity.hasFixedSize()
        binding.listItemAllUsersActivity.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PersonalInfo>()
            .setQuery(
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users"),
                PersonalInfo::class.java
            )
            .build()
        adapter = RecyclerAdapterAllUser(options)
        binding.listItemAllUsersActivity.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter.stopListening()
    }
}
```

firebase database

```
chat-app-3ce78
users
    8tS5NqyvQUaLpo7oVbhCbhDnud82
        LogIn
        PersonalInfo
            age:18
            name: "mohamed"
            nickName: "komy"
    fTppKQYGMxbBPkMoM7A2aMwch332
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I don't get the date from the firebase i always get the name ="", nickname="",age=0

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: i couldn't upload a photo i tried to write the database as it's in the firebase anyway i retrieved the data from the database and passed it to custom recyclerView adapter and worked fine but the firebase recyclerView didn't return any data

Comment: I need to see you real db, as I think that `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")` is causing the problem.

Comment: i can't upload photos because of my reputation i'm new

Comment: You can use [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/).

Comment: https://ibb.co/R0D2wsT 

i changed age to dateOfBirth and changed it in the class too so don't get confused

Comment: It's clear now. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you're trying to use the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
```

To display in you RecyclerView `PersonalInfo` objects. Please note, that this **not** possible since under `users` node, there are actually no such objects. An object of type `PersonalInfo` exists under `PersonalInfo` node, hence that behavior. Besides that, you also missing a child, which is `8tS5NqyvQUaLpo7oVbhCbhDnud82`, being the UID of the user that comes from the authentication process.

To solve this, you should use a query that looks like this:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val usersRef = rootRef.child("users")
val query = usersRef.orderByChild(uid + "/PersonalInfo/name")
```

This `query` object should be passed to the `setQuery()` method in order to get those objects displayed.